# Setting tensorflow.keras.mixed_precision.Policy('mixed_float16') uses up almost all GPU memory

Tags: tensorflow

I noticed that when I call these two lines in my code

```
policy = mixed_precision.Policy('mixed_float16')
mixed_precision.set_policy(policy)
```

My GPU memory spikes and stays that way throughout the rest of my kernel session.  It doesn't go down again until I restart the kernel.
I noticed this when I was trying to train a larger model for image classification but it ran out of memory.

Is this normal?

I'm using tensorflow version 2.4.0

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. According to the [TensorFlow GPU guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth):

> By default, TensorFlow maps nearly all of the GPU memory of all GPUs (subject to `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`) visible to the process. This is done to more efficiently use the relatively precious GPU memory resources on the devices by reducing memory fragmentation.

Using mixed precision allows you to load larger models onto a GPU. It does not necessarily mean that TensorFlow will reserve less GPU memory.

There are two options to limit memory on the GPU. These examples are available in the link at the beginning of this answer.

1. Use `tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth`.

```py
gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  try:
    # Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs
    for gpu in gpus:
      tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Memory growth must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)
```

2. Use `tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration` to set a hard upper limit on GPU memory.

```py
gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  # Restrict TensorFlow to only allocate 1GB of memory on the first GPU
  try:
    tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(
        gpus[0],
        [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=1024)])
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Virtual devices must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)
```